# 2018 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

UX Stack Exchange is scheduled for [an election starting next week, June 18th](https://ux.stackexchange.com/election/3). In connection with that election, we will be hosting a Q&A here for candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3254/2018-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, June 18th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- At the end of the collection phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing (up to) 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

---

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 4):

Participation in this communities Meta site is rather low. Do you feel this is a problem, and if so - how would you go about increasing participation and use of this aspect of the site?

The same goes for the Chat. Most participation of this site is focussed exclusively to the main Q&A page. Is that an issue? How would you change this if so?

Answer (score 2):

A low-quality question is posted by a user with 1 reputation point:

> **show Order history?**
>
> ---
>
> hi. do i show Order history in navigation if they have 0 orders? thanks

Would you be more inclined to

1. start a dialogue to try and teach the asker how the site works and/or guide them to the help center so they can supplement and clarify their question and avoid closure
2. leverage the existing infrastructure for handling such questions and close it with the appropriate reason knowing that any improvements they make will bring the question to the reopen queue

Would your response be different for users with 101 rep (i.e. users that have participated on some other Q&A site)? What about 500+ rep?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 1):

Subjectivity is all part of User Experience design, but Stack Exchange as a platform doesn't really fit well with subjective opinions - it's a Question and Answer site, providing visitors with a curated list of questions around specific problems that User Experience Designers have, and the respective solutions to those problems.

With this in mind, how would you balance deciding what questions are too far into the subjective territory to be appropriate to this site? What criteria do you go by before deciding to cast that binding 'close' (or delete) vote as a moderator?

Answer (score 0):

How would you handle this situation:

A very popular, trivial question is posted (something like: "Why don't Segways have seats?"). It receives *a lot* of votes and answers and generates a large degree of comments and discussions. It has clearly been linked to from an external source and is bringing in lots of new users, some are leaving clearly useless answers ("I like this question!") and others are leaving brief, subjective answers ("I think it is because it looks nicer that way"). It also has answers from existing site members with good reputations and include citations and well though-out reasoning.

It was posted overnight when you weren't available, and you only see this when you first visit the site in the morning. This post gets flagged as being off topic by several users, and you are pretty sure it *is* off topic for the site (it's not really about User Experience, it's more of a "Hmm, what's the deal with this thing not being how I want it to be" question).

How would you deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that moderators should help shape the discussions and conversations of the community so that there is a strong sense of how we want to move forward as a group and the focus of our conversations is clear. I also believe that UXSE can be a forum to help evolve and change the field in a positive manner, and should be used as such so we can become an influence for the wider UX community. With that in mind:

- What is your main passion/interest/expertise in UX design (e.g. ethical design practices)?
- How will you help shape the discussions and conversations in the community in your area of interest?
- What do you think is the main challenge facing UX designers today?
- How do you think we can leverage the collective knowledge and talent on UXSE to address this?